# Performance difference between unary and binary operator

Tags: c++, operators

Is there actually a performance difference between `-foo` and `(-1)*foo` where `foo` is a variable of type `int`?
In theory the unary operator should be faster. But I think the compiler will optimise this out.

Comment: The only definite answer is to inspect the generated instructions.

Comment: _"But I think the compiler will optimise this out."_ I think so too, but you should follow @Quimby's advice.

Comment: @Quimby: Even that is only definite as far as your compiler and settings are concerned. Which is to say, there is no answer both definite and general.

Comment: This is a question that is easily answered by [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/BDZ8mD). gcc 8.2 with -O2 compiles them to the same thing using the `neg` instruction. Edit : Even with no optimization, it produces the same assembly but with extra steps.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux FWIW clang won't optimize away the multiplication without optimizations.

Comment: @cHao ok, I agree with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there actually a performance difference between `-foo` and `(-1)*foo`

Theoretically there can be. The C++ standard makes no guarantees either way.

However, assuming type of `foo` is an integer, then there is absolutely no difference between the observable behaviour of those expressions. The compiler is therefore in that case allowed to generate an identical binary program for either expression. A ideal optimiser should generate the program that that performs better.

Whether your real compiler generates the same output for both programs is another matter - no real compiler is ideal. You can find out by using the compiler for both alternative programs and then comparing the output.

Comment: Of course, the conduct of your compiler today is no guarantee of what a future version of your compiler might do with the code, nor of how it might be compiled for a different target platform. At the end of the day, the most important factor may be which form of code is simpler to read, or is a more clear expression of your intent.